# Is there a local "firewall" to block by "X-Forwarded-For" IPs behind the reverse proxies?

Tags: firewall

The situation is quite typical. I'm using CentOS + Apache(s) behind a Load-balancer for the WebSites.

---

At this point, let's assume i don't have any access to the Load-balancer (or) let's forget about that one.

---

Currently i'm using `.htaccess` to BLOCK the IPs because the native `iptables` is not able to block the `X-Forwarded-For` kind of IP addresses (as far as i understand).

My current approach works anyway. But this still allows my Apache(s) to be hit, at least.

Is there a `firewall` *(like: `iptables`)* which can block the `X-Forwarded-For` IP/connections as well?

Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use string matching in your iptables rule, e,g.

```
iptables -I name 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string 'X-Forwarded-For: 10.1.1.1' -j DROP
```